# Python Exception "as" keyword

Tags: python, exception

Like everthing else, an exception is an object in python. So it can be assigned to a variable using `as` keyword. But what is the purpose of `as` keyword? If I run both examples with or without `as` keyword, I get same result.

**Example 1:**

```
try:
    a = 5
    if a <= 10:
        raise ValueError    
except ValueError as exp:
        print("Please enter a value greater than 10",exp)
```

**Example 2:**

```
try:
    a = 5
    if a <= 10:
        raise ValueError    
except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a value greater than 10")
```

Comment: Did you just answer your own question?  "It can be assigned to a variable using `a`s keyword".  If you don't want to assign the exception to a variable, you don't need the `as` keyword.

Comment: What are further possibilities, methods,attributes etc.?

Comment: `as` assignment is also used in other statements, like `with open(...) as file_:`. *"What are further possibilities"* is bewilderingly broad, could you be specific about what you want to know?

Comment: Doesn't example 1 print something extra? By the way, don't call it exp, especially not if you do: from math import *

Comment: Using as keyword in open function I can read,write a file. But why I need it in an Except statement? Can I call some methods from the Exception class?

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge Nope. Notice how he is simple saying `raise ValueError` instead of `raise ValueError("generic error message")`? He is simply saying raise an exception _object_ not raise an _exception object with an error_.

Comment: Because it creates an exception object that you can print AS YOU DO YOURSELF IN YOUR FIRST EXAMPLE...

Comment: @nawi you need it (or not) for exactly the reason you're using it in your example, so you can get access to the exception object. I do not understand what it is you're trying to ask. *"Can I call some methods from Exception class?"* - have you tried using e.g. `dir` on it? Reading the docs?

Comment: @leaf Indeed he raises a class rather than an object. @ nawi, have you indeed executed your code?

Comment: @Jacques Both outputs are: Please enter a value greater than 10

Comment: @nawi in your first example try writing `raise ValueError("foobar")` instead of `raise ValueError` as I think that will help clear some confusion.

Comment: It's sort of like asking what's the difference between `2+2` and `x=2+2`.  Neither one will display output, but if you assign the value to a variable, you can do something with it later.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  - calling dir was good idea. Thanks

Comment: @BrenBarn Exactly that was my question. What I can do with it later?

Comment: @nawi: Follow leafs advice, then draw a conclusion and if needed edit your question.

Comment: Where does a 500-pound gorilla sleep at night?

Comment: Batman: Where does a 500-pound gorilla sleep? What's worse than a millipede with sore feet? How do you fit five elephants into a car?
Alfred Pennyworth: Wherever it wants, a giraffe with a sore throat, and two in the front seat, two in the back and one in the trunk.

Answer (score 3):

You can do anything you want with the `exp` object in the first case.  In the second case, you can't do anything with it, because it doesn't exist.

You are being confused by the specifics of your example.  You raised ValueError without any error message, so when you print `exp`, it prints nothing.  You can see a difference if you for `print("Please enter a value greater than 10",type(exp))`.  Or, if you do `raise ValueError("Here is a message")`, you will see a message with your original `print`.

In any case, it seems your question is not about `as`, but about what exception objects are.  In your example, you have created an essentially "empty" exception that you can't do much with.  But *in general* an exception object may hold arbitrary information, and if you want to get that information, you would need to capture the exception object in a variable.  Here is a simple example:

```
try:
    b"\xAA\xBB".decode('utf-8')
except UnicodeError as exp:
        print("A unicode error occurred.  Encoding: {}, Reason: {}".format(exp.encoding, exp.reason))
```

The output:

```
A unicode error occurred.  Encoding: utf8, Reason: invalid start byte
```

In this case the UnicodeError object has attributes `encoding` and `reason`.  If you want to access these attributes, you need to capture the exception object.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you basically did `raise ValueError("")` which would show nothing. But if you did `raise ValueError("foo bar")` your output would be `Please enter a value greater than 10 foo bar`. Your basically printing an exception object with no error message.

That however, does not mean that the exception object is not useful. The exception object still has valuable information that may be needed down the road, in which case giving the error an alias using `...as exp` will give you a "handle" so you can still use the object.

---

Here you have a naked exception object. You cannot access the exception object directly from your program, but you need info from that exception object:

[image]

When you use `except ValueError as exp` you can know access the information inside of your exception via `exp`. `exp` works as the reference to your exception:

[image]

<sub>(Waring: this was drawn in MS Paint)</sub>